# Distributed, synchronized batch processing

Tags: java, akka, batch-processing, distributed-computing

In our current Java project, we need to batch process a huge set of records. Once, this processing is done, it must start again and process all records again. This processing must be parallelized as well as distributed among multiple nodes.

The records itself are stored in a database. Using some id range (e.g. 1-10000) for identifying a batch would be sufficient.

From a high level perspective, I see the following steps:

1. A sub task processes one batch of records.
2. A master task checks if any sub task is still running. If not, create one sub task for each batch of records.

We use MongoDB quite heavily and thought of persisting sub tasks in it. Then, each node can pick up sub tasks that are not done yet, does the processing and marks the record as done. Once there are no undone subtasks, the master task creates all the sub tasks again. This would probably work, but we are looking for a solution in which we don't need to do the heavy synchronization work ourselves.

- Could this be a possible use-case for [akka](http://akka.io/)?
- Can [akka-persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.0/scala/persistence.html) be used to synchronize the processing among different nodes?
- Are there any other Java/JVM frameworks suited for this job?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is way too broad for SO's format. Plase read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the future before asking, and don't ask your group members to vote your question up just to inflate what is obviously an ill-posed question ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°).

Anyways:

1) Yes, you can implement your requirements in Akka. In particular, since you mentioned multiple nodes, you are looking at the akka-cluster module (for inter-node communication), and you might also need akka-cluster-sharding (in case you want to keep all data in memory beside during processing).

2) No, I would strongly not reccomend that. While you could technically force your problem into using akka-persistence for synchronizing the tasks, the goal of akka-persistence is simply to make an actor's state persistent. Akka itself in its basic form is enough for handling all your synchronization issues. Simply have a master actor create a worker for every subtask and monitor its completion.

3) Yes. Note that the answer to this question is always yes no matter *which* job.